# How to find the min value in interval that added distance falls inside another interval?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

suppose I have an interval [360, 420[, a distance of 89 and a set of intervals [480, 540[, [600, 660[, [1020, 1080[ and [1200, 1260[
The first value on the first interval added with 89 that falls in one of the interval set in 391 (391 + 89 = 480)

What is the most efficient algorithm or implementation in python to get this result?

I know that it is possible to loop through the first interval with increments of 1 and get the result however, I wonder if there is a specific algorithm other brute force...

Answer (score 2):

Do a set intersection and take the minimum:

```
>>> interval = range(360, 420)
>>> distance = 89
>>> other_intervals = [range(480, 540), range(600, 660), range(1020, 1080), range(1200, 1260)]
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> min(
...     set(range(interval.start + distance, interval.stop + distance)) 
...     & reduce(set.union, map(set, other_intervals), set())
) - distance
391
```

Comment: The algorithm is equivalent to the brute force method that the OP said they would like to avoid. `set(range(5))` is `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`, so `set(range(interval.start + distance, interval.stop + distance))` is a set of all the numbers in the range, making the set intersection equivalent to a "loop through the first interval with increments of 1".

Answer (score 2):

Here is an algorithm that is much faster than iterating through every integer in the range. It instead iterates over every interval in the list and uses comparisons and subtraction to find the desired values. It is `O(n)` complexity with regard to the length of the list of intervals, and `O(1)` for the size of the intervals.

```
class interval:
    "An interval of the form [a, b["
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def is_inside(self, other):
        return any(other.a <= x < other.b for x in [self.a, self.b - 1])

    def intersects(self, other):
        return self.is_inside(other) or other.is_inside(self)

    def find_intersection(self, others):
        for i, other in enumerate(others):
            if self.intersects(other):
                # if other.a >= self.a, offset is the difference
                # between other.a and self.a, otherwise self.a > other.a,
                # so the lower bound of self is inside the other interval,
                # so the offset is 0 away from the lower bound
                offset = other.a - self.a if other.a >= self.a else 0
                return i, offset

    def __add__(self, offset):
        return interval(self.a + offset, self.b + offset)


other_intervals = [interval(480, 540), interval(600, 660), interval(1020, 1080), interval(1200, 1260)]

# The interval [360, 420[ + 89 falls within the
# first interval in the list (index 0), and is 31 into
# the interval, (i.e. 360+31+89=480) hence the
# result (0, 31)
print((interval(360, 420) + 89).find_intersection(other_intervals))

# Neither a distance of 1 nor 100000 puts the
# first interval inside any of the others, so
# it returns None
print((interval(360, 420) + 1).find_intersection(other_intervals))
print((interval(360, 420) + 100000).find_intersection(other_intervals))

# 360 + 183 + 57 = 600, which is the lower bound of the
# second interval (index 1), hence the result (1, 57)
print((interval(360, 420) + 183).find_intersection(other_intervals))

# if the lower bound of the first interval is inside the
# other interval, the offset is 0: 360 + 121 = 481, whic
# is already inside [480, 540[, so nothing else needs to be added
print((interval(360, 420) + 121).find_intersection(other_intervals))
```

This function returns the offset within the interval, for example 31 for the example in your question. If you want to obtain 391, just do 360 + 31.